# cloze solver not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been using python for some time, I have a file that is the english alphabet with each word on separate lines, and I have ironed out all the errors, but it doesn't type anything anymore. I'm open to any help, and improvements to the code, provided you explain how it works. If you are looking for the file it is [here](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt)

```js
f = open("C:\\my folders\\brit-a-z.txt", 'r')

print("Type in your cloze word like this: cl-z-")
def cloze(word):
    for line in f:
        match = True
        if len(line) == len(word):
            for i in range(len(word)):
                if not word[i]  == "-":
                    if line[i] == word[i]:
                        match == False
            if match == True:
                print(line)

while True:
    cloze(input())
```

Comment: ``match == False`` you probably meant to write ``match = False``

Comment: or you meant `if line[i] != word[i]: match = False`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've iterated through the file for the first word, the file closes. You'll need to save f. For example:

```
with open("C:\\my folders\\brit-a-z.txt", 'r') as f:
      f = f.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped